# NameError: uninitialized constant Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError when upgrading to rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, shoulda

I'm trying to upgrade my rails application to Rails3.

When I run functional tests, I get a lot of `NameError: uninitialized constant Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError` errors. But unit tests and website itself seems to work fine.

Trace looks like this:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError
/Users/mantas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing_from_s3_library'
/Users/mantas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/shoulda-02520e4/lib/shoulda/action_controller/matchers/redirect_to_matcher.rb:52:in `rescue in redirects_to_url?'
/Users/mantas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/shoulda-02520e4/lib/shoulda/action_controller/matchers/redirect_to_matcher.rb:48:in `redirects_to_url?'
/Users/mantas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/shoulda-02520e4/lib/shoulda/action_controller/matchers/redirect_to_matcher.rb:35:in `matches?'
/Users/mantas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/shoulda-02520e4/lib/shoulda/assertions.rb:53:in `assert_accepts'
/Users/mantas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/shoulda-02520e4/lib/shoulda/context.rb:324:in `block in should'
/Users/mantas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/shoulda-02520e4/lib/shoulda/context.rb:382:in `call'
/Users/mantas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/shoulda-02520e4/lib/shoulda/context.rb:382:in `block in create_test_from_should_hash'
```

Both Shoulda and Amazon S3 gems are latest versions.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been reported http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/issue/117.

The work around (that at least makes this error go away, not sure if it *actually* works right) is:

```
unless defined?(Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError)
  class Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError < ActiveSupport::TestCase::Assertion
  end
end
```

Comment: Ooops - I forgot to metion, i put that snippet in test/test_helper.rb

Answer (score 6):

Ash Berlin's solution will make the exception go away, but it will make any matchers that `try` and `catch` `Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError` fail.  If `AssertionFailedError` is an `ActiveSupport::TestCase::Assertion`, and you throw an `ActiveSupport::TestCase::Assertion`, you will not catch it as a `Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError`.  He has his inheritance relationship backwards.  Instead, put this in your `test_helper.rb`:

```
unless defined?(Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError)
  Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError = ActiveSupport::TestCase::Assertion
end
```